# RPi.GPIO error: Name error: RPi

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, pi-2

When testing my code on my RPi 2 B, I come along a name 'RPI' is not defined error. Can someone please help me to figure out why this is happening?

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import colorsys
import time
import picamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


class Process_Picture(object):
  ''' loop through each pixel and average rgb '''
  def __init__(self, imageName):

      self.pic = imageName    
      self.imgData = self.pic.load()

  def averagePixels(self):
      r, g, b = 0, 0, 0
      count = 0
      for x in range(int(self.pic.size[0])):
          for y in range(int(self.pic.size[1])):
              tempr,tempg,tempb = self.imgData[x,y]
              r += tempr
              g += tempg
              b += tempb
              count += 1
      # calculate averages
      ravg = int(r/count)
      gavg = int(g/count)
      bavg = int(b/count)
 #    print(ravg, gavg, bavg, count)
      return (ravg,gavg,bavg)

  def computeDGCI(self, rg, gg, bg):
      h,s,v =colorsys.rgb_to_hsv( rg/255, gg/255, bg/255 )
      print (h, s, v)
      HUE = 360*h
      print (HUE)
      DGCI = (((HUE-60)/60 + (1-s) + (1-v))/3)
      print (DGCI)
      return DGCI

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        curr_time = time.localtime()
        if curr_time.tm_hour == 15 and curr_time.tm_min == 36:
            print(curr_time)
            with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
                camera.resolution = (400, 400)
                camera.start_preview
                time.sleep ( 2 )
                camera.capture('test.jpg')
            picture1 = Image.open("test.jpg")

        #    picture1.imgData = picture1.load()                     
            pc1 = Process_Picture(picture1)
            a,b,c = pc1.averagePixels()
            print(a,b,c)
            pc1.computeDGCI(a, b, c)


        #   Divide picture in four parts

            x = int(picture1.size[0])
            y = int(picture1.size[1])
            x1 = int(picture1.size[0]/2)
            y1 = int(picture1.size[1]/2)

            picture1_1 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (0,0,x1,y1))
            picture1_2 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (x1,0,x,y1))
            picture1_3 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (0,y1,x1,y))
            picture1_4 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (x1,y1,x,y))

        #   Compute DGCI for image segment1    
        #    picture1_1.imgData = picture1_1.load()                     
            pc1_1 = Process_Picture(picture1_1)
            R1_1,G1_1,B1_1 = pc1_1.averagePixels()
            print(R1_1,G1_1,B1_1)
            DGCI_1_1 = pc1_1.computeDGCI(R1_1,G1_1,B1_1)

        #   Compute DGCI for image segment2    
        #    picture1_2.imgData = picture1_2.load()                     
            pc1_2 = Process_Picture(picture1_2)
            R1_2,G1_2,B1_2 = pc1_2.averagePixels()
            print(R1_2,G1_2,B1_2)
            DGCI_1_2 = pc1_2.computeDGCI(R1_2,G1_2,B1_2)

        #   Compute DGCI for image segment3
        #   picture1_3.imgData = picture1_3.load()                     
            pc1_3 = Process_Picture(picture1_3)
            R1_3,G1_3,B1_3= pc1_3.averagePixels()
            print(R1_3,G1_3,B1_3)
            DGCI_1_3 = pc1_3.computeDGCI(R1_3,G1_3,B1_3)

        #   Compute DGCI for image segment4
        #   picture1_4.imgData = picture1_4.load()                     
            pc1_4 = Process_Picture(picture1_4)
            R1_4,G1_4,B1_4 = pc1_4.averagePixels()
            print(R1_4,G1_4,B1_4)
            DGCI_1_4 = pc1_4.computeDGCI(R1_4,G1_4,B1_4)
            time.sleep(60)
            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
            RPI.GPIO.setup(2, RPi.GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(24, 1)         
            sleep(3)              
            GPIO.output(24, 0)         
            sleep(3)   



        if curr_time.tm_hour == 16 and curr_time.tm_min == 00:
            print(curr_time)
            with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
                camera.resolution = (400, 400)
                camera.start_preview
                time.sleep ( 2 )
                camera.capture('test.jpg')
            picture1 = Image.open("test.jpg")

        #   picture1.imgData = picture1.load()                     
            pc1 = Process_Picture(picture1)
            a,b,c = pc1.averagePixels()
            print(a,b,c)
            pc1.computeDGCI(a, b, c)


        #   Divide picture in four parts

            x = int(picture1.size[0])
            y = int(picture1.size[1])
            x1 = int(picture1.size[0]/2)
            y1 = int(picture1.size[1]/2)

            picture1_1 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (0,0,x1,y1))
            picture1_2 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (x1,0,x,y1))
            picture1_3 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (0,y1,x1,y))
            picture1_4 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (x1,y1,x,y))

        #   Compute DGCI for image segment1    
        #   picture1_1.imgData = picture1_1.load()                     
            pc1_1 = Process_Picture(picture1_1)
            R1_1,G1_1,B1_1 = pc1_1.averagePixels()
            print(R1_1,G1_1,B1_1)
            DGCI_1_1 = pc1_1.computeDGCI(R1_1,G1_1,B1_1)

        #   Compute DGCI for image segment2    
        #   picture1_2.imgData = picture1_2.load()                     
            pc1_2 = Process_Picture(picture1_2)
            R1_2,G1_2,B1_2 = pc1_2.averagePixels()
            print(R1_2,G1_2,B1_2)
            DGCI_1_2 = pc1_2.computeDGCI(R1_2,G1_2,B1_2)

        #   Compute DGCI for image segment3
        #   picture1_3.imgData = picture1_3.load()                     
            pc1_3 = Process_Picture(picture1_3)
            R1_3,G1_3,B1_3= pc1_3.averagePixels()
            print(R1_3,G1_3,B1_3)
            DGCI_1_3 = pc1_3.computeDGCI(R1_3,G1_3,B1_3)

        #   Compute DGCI for image segment4
        #   picture1_4.imgData = picture1_4.load()                     
            pc1_4 = Process_Picture(picture1_4)
            R1_4,G1_4,B1_4 = pc1_4.averagePixels()
            print(R1_4,G1_4,B1_4)
            DGCI_1_4 = pc1_4.computeDGCI(R1_4,G1_4,B1_4)
            time.sleep (60)
            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
            GPIO.output(24, 1)         
            sleep(3)              
            GPIO.output(24, 0)         
            sleep(3)   

        else:
            print ("Not time yet!")
            time.sleep(60)
```

[image: Picture of error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change RPi.GPIO.setup(2, RPi.GPIO.OUT) to GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT) since you used the as statement when you imported the RPi.GPIO library.

Comment: Or just import RPi.GPIO.  I suppose it is to do with namespaces.  import RPi.GPIO creates a namespace RPi.GPIO whose symbols can be referenced as RPi.GPIO.  import RPi.GPIO as X creates a namespace X whose symbols can be referenced as X.